# How to have an ASP checkbox for each entry in a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, web-controls

I want to do something like this in my asp code:

```
<%
 foreach Record record in listOfRecords
{
 %>
<asp:checkbox runat="server" id="employeeIdNumber" />
<p>Employee's Name: <%= record.name %> </p>
<p>Employee's Phone Number: <%= record.phoneNumber %></p>
<%
}
%>
```

The problem is that the checkbox id is a string literal.  How can I give a unique id to each employee's checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap this in a repeater.  Then bind your listOfRecords to the repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:checkbox runat="server" id="employeeIdNumber" />
    <p>Employee's Name: <%# Eval("name") %> </p>
    <p>Employee's Phone Number: <%# Eval("phoneNumber") %></p>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then to get it out, you run through the RepeaterItems collection and look for the checkboxes by RepeaterItem.FindControl("employeeIdNumber") to determine if they are checked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Repeater instead.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptEmployees" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="employeeIDNumber" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This Control will render unique ID for each checkbox for you.

Answer (score 0):

CheckboxList is an option too.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx

This also has an example on how to check the checked state - just iterate through and check the Selected property.